# Cannot select inserted data

Tags: php, mysql

I made a new table , everything worked.
 `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logdata (
email varchar(30),
password varchar(20),
username varchar(15),)`
Inserted the id auto increment code 
 ,and some data :

```
INSERT INTO logdata(email,password,username,id) VALUES('test@test.org','testtest1','test',' ')
```

Everything worked here.  When I try to output the data i dont get any results (except "ERROR").  I have no idea why.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
// here is where I set the connection , everything is working here
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Could not connect to the database <br /><br />";
echo mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}

$dostuff="SELECT * FROM logdata";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $dostuff);
if($query == TRUE)   {
    echo "Succes!";
}    
else{
    echo "ERROR ";
    echo mysqli_error($db_conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error message in question?

Comment: my head hurts.... what does the error message say?

Comment: What error message do you get?  What is `$dostuff`?  We can't help you without more information.

Comment: Maybe its saying that you have **no query** in your *query* because `$dostuff=""` is empty?

Comment: Also, if your `id` column is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` you don't need it in your query and ensure that your DB credentials/connection are well established.

Comment: P.S. `mysqli_query` returns a result set for `SELECT` queries, not a boolean.  It only returns `TRUE` for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: I'll call this `C.O.W.` code for now, till I see actual/full code.

Comment: All nice and dandy that you edited your question with `$dostuff="SELECT * FROM userdata";` but that doesn't explain your `INSERT...` show us the actual code and how you're using this. Voted to close till I do see it, along with the error message.

Comment: Your code will *always* echo `"ERROR"` because `mysqli_query` will *NEVER* return `TRUE`.  `$query === TRUE` will always be `FALSE`.  When doing a `SELECT` query, `mysqli_query` returns a resource.  You need to then call `fetch_assoc` (or whatever) to get the data.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: But it didn't return the data from the table!

Comment: @Fred-ii This is the full code

Comment: No, you have `INSERT INTO logdata...` on top of your question, which is not implemented in your posted code. @user3174814

Comment: @Fred-ii- I posted the full code , however I dont remember the id auto increment code .

Comment: `$dostuff="SELECT * FROM userdata";` <-- should this be logdata?

Comment: Well that makes sense @DampeS8N

Comment: @dampes8n  It should , but THIS doesen't solve the problem...

Comment: @user3174814 Yes, because changing `if($query === TRUE)   {` to `if($query == TRUE)   {` will (as in DontVoteMeDown's answer)

Comment: @dampes8n It is changed but the output is still nothing...

Comment: is it nothing, or is it still just saying "ERROR"?

Comment: @dampes8n nothing ,  BTW soon need I to go , so I will answerall other questions tomorrow.

Comment: You have a syntax error now. You can't have an if statement and else that both start with an echo which results in no output. Please turn on error reporting to find your syntax error. Once you clear that, you are probably out of the woods. Good luck.

Comment: @dampes8n Reporting is turned on , look at the first line of the code please.

Comment: Add ini_set('display_errors', true); after error_reporting(E_ALL); and try again.

Comment: @PeteR Stil nothing...

Answer (score 2):

In order to *query* something in your database, you have to **provide a query** to it. Your query variable is an empty string!!

```
$dostuff="";
```

It should have some SQL statements, like e.g:

```
$dostuff="SELECT * FROM logdata";
```

Or whatever.

**UPDATE**

I believe that using `===` to test the result will fail because the `mysqli_query` returns a [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, [according to the docs](http://php.net/mysqli_query#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So if its succeful it won't be `=== TURE` for your `SELECT` statement and it will have no error. Your query is fine, just try this:

```
if ($query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $dostuff)) {
    echo "Success!";
}    
else {
    echo "ERROR ";
    echo mysqli_error($db_conn);
}
```

It should works.

Comment: Im Sorry , but this isn't it , i left the query empty in purpouse, I will change it now , to prevent future mistakes

Comment: @user3174814 Damn dude, we got no crystal ball.

Comment: @user3174814 You have updated your code but not provided the error message, what is the most important thing here!

Comment: Basiclly , The error message is just "ERROR"

Comment: @user3174814 It's impossible, because "ERROR" is your message. `mysqli_error()` should provide a message itself seeing that `$query` is `false`. Its strange.

Comment: Thank You , but it still doesn't work

Comment: @user3174814 did you tried **this** if: `if ($query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $dostuff))` ??

Comment: Thank You , but this isn't the problem , the problem is , that i dont get ANY result

Comment: @user3174814 if the connection is ok and the table has data, it should return a result by a simple query like yours. If it still returning empty, maybe you should delete everything and start you project over again.